# Newletter missing from admin panel in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, admin-panel, newsletter

I have an interesting problem and I don't know where to find the issue. Newsletter tab from admin doesn't show, you can see the photos I attached to compare:
[image: Newsletter displays]

In this photo you can see how it should display the newsletter tab.

[image: Newsletter doesn't display]

I've checked in the **System->Configuration->Advanced** and the module is enabled, so that's not the problem.

More than that I've inspected the element from my browser and I found the problem but I don't know how to resolve it. The code looks like this:

```
<li onmouseover="Element.addClassName(this,'over')" onmouseout="Element.removeClassName(this,'over')" class="  parent level0"> <a href="#" onclick="return false" class="">
     <span></span></a>
<ul>
<li class="  level1"> <a href="https://nala.ro/index.php/admin_n414/newsletter_template/index/key/a3dd656ad998f9adaaeead6d98eceb12/" class=""><span>Șabloane</span></a>
</li>
<li class="  level1"> <a href="https://nala.ro/index.php/admin_n414/newsletter_queue/index/key/f41c7af14effa5b56377168cf1f869b3/" class=""><span>Coadă Newsletter</span></a>
</li>
<li class="  level1"> <a href="https://nala.ro/index.php/admin_n414/newsletter_subscriber/index/key/d3591a8154f921ea0ad212785faa4bb4/" class=""><span>Abonați</span></a>
</li>
<li class="  level1"> <a href="https://nala.ro/index.php/admin_n414/newsletter_problem/index/key/21be41fa5dc60f626eb678c2e32eaf7e/" class=""><span>Rapoarte Probleme Newsletter</span>
</a>
</li>
<li onmouseover="Element.addClassName(this,'over')" onmouseout="Element.removeClassName(this,'over')" class="  parent last level1"> 
<a href="#" onclick="return false" class=""><span>Mailchimp</span></a>
<ul>
<li class="  last level2"> <a href="https://nala.ro/index.php/admin_n414/mailchimperrors/index/key/75e5bbad7d0d6c536c7f9cd6ce4e9465/" class=""><span>Mailchimp Errors</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

So, the element exists but no text is completed between the `<span>` tags. If I completed manually will appear in the menu. I think the problem could be a conflict between modules. Can anyone help me with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Does the problem persist if you change the backend language? If no, it could be some malformatted CSV translation file.

Comment: wow, this was the problem, but now the problem is that on my localhost 'newsletter' is displayed indifferent the selected laguage, only on my website I have this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your comment

Comment: The "newsletter" tab is displayed on my localhost regardless of the selected language, but on my live website I have is not displayed on one of my language.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid translation strings can be responsible for such a behavior. Make sure there are no invalid characters (or one that could break the integrity of the CSV file -- basically almost every special character has the potential to do so) in your translation csv files that are not surrounded by `"`.

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is only on my live website. When I change the language on my localhost it is working.

Comment: did you check your `app/locale/ro_RO/Mage_Newsletter.csv` (note: `ro_RO` is just an assumption based on your domain) for potential problems? If it is not the csv it possibly could be some inline-translated string as well.